# Can I migrate to Woo Commerce from Big Commerce

Tags: woocommerce, content-management-system, hosting, bigcommerce

Have been using BigCommerce for quite sometime for my online store. Now that they are increasing the price, I'm pondering about switching to another platform.

Wordpress with Woocommerce certainly did catch my attention. Wanted to find out if anybody had moved from Bigcommerce to Woocommerce successfully (or to any other platform for that matter) and if yes, are you missing anything as far as features or ease of use concerned.

Did the move affect sales/customer satisfaction? Also any comments on any potential problems highly appreciated too.

Comment: It's impossible to migrate your BigCommerce to WooCommerce manually. A [**Shopping Cart Migration Service**](https://next-cart.com/supported-carts/woocommerce/) is what you are looking for. Don't be afraid to change, it is essential, and it only affects your customers well.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in the subject: Yes, a migration should be possible using a tool like [Shopping Cart Migration](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/)

To your second question: I have no experience with this tool or a shop to shop migration in general. Important points that come to my mind:

- Replication of the design and functionality of the front end
- Migration of user data
- Migration of order data (connected to user data)
- Migration of stored credit card information (in case of stored subscriptions)

Comment: Bigcommerce cannot store credit card data, so this would be unnecessary. Another concern is migrating user data and Bigcommerce not allowing the export of passwords (which are salted and hashed anyway).
Migration of catalog and product data is fundamental. As well as some static pages you may have.